# How can I rotate a video by a few degrees?

Tags: video, video-editing

I've taken a fairly tilted video and want to rotate it to be level, how can I do this?  I'm open to any third-party apps but purely apple solutions are better.  I have FCPX, but I don't know if I can use that.

Comment: @Tetsujin I've Googled a bunch and I couldn't find any apps or ways I could rotate it.  And Preview doesn't do it. That's it.

Answer (score 1):

1. Import the video in FCPX (don't worry about creating optimised/proxy media, etc).
2. Create a project and add the clip.
3. Use Transform (⇧T) to rotate (and scale) the clip as appropriate.
4. Export.

Comment: Export as what? Master file or 1080 or???

Comment: Sorry it took me so long to respond.  Ok, but my original file is 600mb, when I crop and try to export as the Master File, it says it's going to be approximately 10gb.  How is that possible?

Comment: @Emmet Arries If you export a master file it will be in the format (codec) set by your project settings. By default this will be ProRes 422 unless you manually set it to something else. It will not be likely to be set to the same codec as your incoming, compressed, footage. ProRes 422 produces large file sizes but it is designed for the editing process. To export in a more useful, compressed, format: use the "share" button in FCPX and choose one which roughly matches your 600MB original.

Comment: @MicChannel Thanks for the advice! I will use that!